# Plotting “mark groups” with different colors

Tags: python, igraph

I am very new to igraph, and have been plotting out a project of mine. In my python code I used the:

```
igraph.VertexClustering.FromAttribute(graph, attribute)
```

to identify the groups.

The problem is the coloring of this VertexCluster. When using the VertexCluster as “mark_groups” for the visual style, the groups are grey. Despite using “mark_col”, it does not change.
[Example of the grey marked groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7PvQ.png)

How do I change the colors for mark_groups when using a VertexClustering.FromAttribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't know the exact code I don't know what's wrong. I've just created a working example based on [this description](https://igraph.org/python/tutorial/develop/tutorials/cluster_graph/cluster_graph.html)

```py
import igraph as ig
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = ig.Graph(edges=[(0, 1), (1, 2), (3, 4), (4, 5)])
g.vs["cluster"] = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
g.vs["color"] = ["red", "blue", "blue", "green", "orange", "gold"]

communities = ig.VertexClustering.FromAttribute(g, "cluster")

num_communities = len(communities)
palette = ig.RainbowPalette(n=num_communities)
for i, community in enumerate(communities):
    g.vs[community]["color"] = i   # Remove this to keep the original colors
    community_edges = g.es.select(_within=community)
    community_edges["color"] = i

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ig.plot(
    communities,
    target=ax,
    mark_groups=True,
    palette=palette
)

fig.savefig("clusters.png")
```

[image: using the group's color for edges]

I tried to remove the first line in the for cycle to keep the original colors, but not all the colors was kept that was defined in the `g.vs["color"] = ...` line. I don't know the reason. I got this:

[image: keeping vertex colors]

Comment: I had the same problem. Found out  you can add the "vertex_color" for the visual style after the "mark_groups", which will override the assigned colors. Assign the verts for a color dict. This is my result: https://imgur.com/a/ZVsJI4U